# Finding the coordinates of the farthest point from a point inside an ellipse without knowing a or b?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out. I have an ellipse and the known info is that the major axis is horizontal the center is at (0,0), there is a point P at (0, $\dfrac{3}{2}$), the maximum distance from this point to anywhere on the ellipse is $\sqrt{7}$, and $\dfrac{c}{a}$ =  ${\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$ (c is the foci length, a is the major axis length). Is there any way to find the equation of this ellipse and the coordinates of the furthest point on the ellipse from P? Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: From goofing off on Geogebra for a few minutes, it would seem that the line segment from a point inside an ellipse to the furthest point on the boundary is normal to the ellipse.  That's more analytic geometry that I'm willing to do for free ^_^, but at least it might give you an idea of how to leverage that clue.

Comment: What is a "horizontal" ellipse?! Moreover, I can *guess* what your $a$ and $c$ mean, but this is a mathematical site, so I'd strongly suggest you *define* them!

Comment: @layabout, yess P is inside the ellipse

Comment: @qfwfq a horizontal ellipse is where the major axis is horizontal, c is the foci length, a is the major axis length

Comment: @layabout sqrt(3)/2 is not greater than 1? it is roughly 0.866

Comment: Sorry I read it as $3/2$.

Comment: @Matthew Daly I Know that the line from P to the edge of the ellipse is greater when it is perpendicular to the tangent line at that point, I just don't really know how to proceed with this problem from here

Comment: That point Q(x,y) on the edge of the ellipse is on the circle centered at P with radius $\sqrt 7$ and you know the slope of the tangent to the ellipse.  That seems like enough information to nail down the equation of the ellipse given that it's horizontal, so you just have to find the specific point on Q on that circle that creates the eccentricity you want.

Comment: @Matthew Daly, sorry the circle is centered at the origin and im still a bit confused, I tried algebra and it isn't working well

Comment: If you relax the condition that the point is inside the ellipse, I get $(x/2)^2+y^2=1.$

Comment: @Jan-Magnus Økland sorry but I can't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{c}{a}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\to c=\frac{\sqrt{3} a}{2}$$
we know that $$b^2=a^2-c^2\to a^2=4b^2$$
The equation of the ellipse is
$$\frac{x^2}{4b^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
Write the ellipse in parametric form
$$E:(x=2b\cos t,y=b\sin t)$$
The distance between the point $P(0,3/2)$  and a generic point of the ellipse is
$$EP^2=f(b)=(2b\cos t)^2+\left(b\sin t-\frac32\right)^2=b^2 \sin ^2 t+4 b^2 \cos ^2 t-3 b \sin t+\frac{9}{4}$$
derivative is zero in $[0,2\pi]$ if
$$f'(b)= -3 b \cos t (2 b \sin t+1)=0$$
$$ t=\pm\pi/2;\;t=2\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right);\;t=\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)$$
Looking at the second derivative $f''(b)=3 b (\sin t-2 b \cos 2t)$, if $b>\frac{1}{2}$ the maximum is $t=\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)$
$$f\left(\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)\right)=7$$ if $$4 b^2+3=7\to b^2=1$$
The equation of the ellipse is
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2=1$$
and the coordinates of the most distant point are
$$\left(\pm\sqrt{3},-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

**Edit**

You can't have an ellipse with point $P$ internal and $\sqrt 7$ maximum distance. See the second picture below.

---

$$...$$
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution thank you! only problem is that the point P should be inside of the ellipse, not outside.

Comment: @IhaveAquestion Why do you believe that there can be another solution?

Comment: @user I don't know but I do know that the point P should be inside the ellipse, which it is not for Raffaele's solution, as stated in the problem

Comment: @IhaveAquestion But there is no other solution with the given parameters. You should relax some of them. You have necessarily $a=2b$ and already from this fact it is impossible to have another ellipse with the **farthest** point at a distance $\sqrt7$. Look at the picture and imagine to scale the ellipse (the circle has radius $\sqrt7$).

Comment: @user this is my mistake, I reread the problem and yes, it can be inside or outside. Thank you so much for your help. You and Raffaele are truly amazing

Comment: @IhaveAquestion I edited the answer to add the reason why $P$ can't be internal. Hope this helps

Comment: @Raffaele, yes that clarifies everything thank you so much for your help, have an amazing day